# copy chars from a string into another in visual c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, substring

I have a `char[]` say str1, how do I copy few chars from str1 to another `char[]` say str2. Like in java you normally use `String` method `substring()` for String. Can I do that for a `char[]`?

> ```
> str2 = str1.substring(3,6);
> ```

Does CString have such function? And can I convert a `char[]` to `CString`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/

Answer (score 2):

C++ has `std::string` equivalent of Java `String`. Make an `#include<string>` and then use its [`substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method in similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Microsoft CString, use the Mid method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms928955.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes CString does have such a method. As you mention CString it is clear that you are using Windows and MFC. The std::string contained in STL is possibly a better choice especially for non ANSI strings. The Qt framework also has an excellent string class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the c-function [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) :

> char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num
>   );

**example:**

```
#include <string.h>
char* str1 = "this is my awesome string";
char* str2 = new char[4];
// str + 3 because you wanna copy 3 elements
// starting at index 3 (this is in fact pointer "magic")
// so: "s i" is copied into str2
str2 = strncpy(str2, str1 + 3, 3);
```

Comment: `strncpy` is notoriously hard to use.  It also might not be obvious to a novice that an important bit is that `new char[4]` zero initializes the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++'s [**`std::string`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) rather than arrays of `char` (the **C** way), it's very versatile and will save you the worry of buffer overruns and the like.

Here's a quick demonstration, which [you can see running here](http://ideone.com/mteBP)...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "how do I copy few chars?";

    // Create a std::string from char pointers
    std::string str2(str1 + 3, str1 + 9);
    std::cout << "str2 = '" << str2 << "'" << std::endl;

    // Create a std::string from another
    std::string str3 = str2.substr(1, 4);
    std::cout << "str3 = '" << str3 << "'" << std::endl;

    // Create a std::string from a literal
    std::string str4 = "Goodbye!";
    std::cout << "str4 = '" << str4 << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for copy chars you can also try like this.... But very careful while dealing with memory spaces

```
char str1[] = "beatiful chik",str2[5];
ZeroMemory(str2,5);
int start= 9,Length = 4;
memcpy(str2,&str1[start],sizeof(char)*Length);
AfxMessageBox(str2);
```